# PHP how to echo certain result if associative value is not in array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array = [
    "123" => ["name" => "Tom", "age" => "15"],
    "456" => ["name" => "Dick", "age" => "16"],
    "789" => ["name" => "Harry", "age" => "17"]
];
```

I have a HTML form that requires you to enter a 3 digit number and it is stored as $number via $_POST, and if it exists within the array, it will echo out the number that is in the array and if it doesn't exist it will echo out Fail. I can manage to echo out the existing number in the array but not Fail, how do I go around doing this? I use a foreach loop and within the foreach loop I use an if statement.

```
<?php
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if($number == $key){
        echo $key;
    }
}
?>
```

With this, if I type in 123, 456 or 789, it will echo out correspondingly. But now I want it to echo Fail if I type something non-existent in the array, like 999.
Yes I am aware that I can simply just type

```
else{
    echo"Fail";
}
```

But for some reason the output will be FailFailFail, I think this is due to the foreach loop. Any idea? Not to mention, just by simply adding else statement, the FailFailFail is already echoed out before the user even attempts his first try at entering the number.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just add a Flag

```
 <?php
        $flag = 0;
        foreach($array as $key => $value)
        {
           if($number == $key)
           {
              echo $key;
              $flag = 1;
           }
        }
        if($flag == 0)
        {
            echo "fail";
        }
    ?>
```

This will do the work. :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to iterate with `foreach()` at all - you can replace the entire block like this, simply checking to see if the corresponding key exists:

```
if (isset($array[$number])) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

Comment: Sorry guys if I miss out any sufficient details earlier, I've updated my question already would you evaluate it again? The reason for me using a foreach loop was to echo out the existing number itself in the array if there was such a number and if there wasn't it would echo Fail. So if I type in 123, it will echo 123 etc. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Then this answer is still correct...Swap `'success'` with `$number`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an "else" statement

```
else {
   echo "Failed";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it write `FailFailFail` because you are looping entire array and testing all keys - which is needless. Try this:

```
$number = $_POST['number']; // or wherefrom you take the value from form

 $array = [
    "123" => ["name" => "Tom", "age" => "15"],
    "456" => ["name" => "Dick", "age" => "16"],
    "789" => ["name" => "Harry", "age" => "17"]
];

if (isset($array[$number])) {
    echo $number;
    // or var_dump($array[$number]);
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```